# How should I implement the Func in AddOrUpdate() in this object: ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<MyObject>>

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

How do I implement `AddorUpdate` in ConcurrentDictionary so that I can correctly update the value, if that value is a collection?

My concern is that since TValue is a reference type I might run into the situation where I call TValue multiple times in a race condition.  I would test this myself, but my syntax is wrong so I can't proceed further.

What must I change to make this work?

```
   public class TrustList :  ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<TrustRelationshipDetail>>
    {
        public void AddOrUpdateTrustDetail(TrustRelationshipDetail detail)
        {
            List<TrustRelationshipDetail> detailList = new List<TrustRelationshipDetail>();
            detailList.Add(detail);

            this.AddOrUpdate(detail.HierarchyDepth, detailList, (key, oldValue) =>   
            oldValue.Add(detail)  // <--- Compiler doesn't like this, and I think this may cause duplicates if this were to be called...
           );
        }
    }
```

Comment: That won't work, since `List<T>` is not threadsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `AddOrUpdate()` is to *replace* any existing value with a new value.

Since you only need to *get* the existing value (in order to then modify it), you want `GetOrAdd()`:

```
this.GetOrAdd(detail.HierarchyDepth, new ConcurrentBag<TrustRelationshipDetail>())
        .Add(detail);
```

Comment: This answer is perfect in so many ways. It would have taken me forever to see it this clearly (if at all)